# Android - Organizing levels in a game

Tags: java, android

I'm new in the development with Android. For a school project, I'm currently working on an application for children to help them learn writing.
The app will contain many levels that use the same concept, only the background changes. I have made a level that works fine and now to finish the work, I want to add levels using the code of the first one.

So what is a good/usual way to do that ?

I thought that I could create as many activities as levels. In each new activity, I could start the first one and give it the new background as parameter. But with 50+ levels, it seems a bit strange to me to have so many activities.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fragments, particularly 1 type of **Fragment** called '`LevelFragment`' which will have a few arguments that you can pass to it so that each level is different, those arguments should refer to the content of the level (background or whatever). This way you're **reusing** the same layout and the same logic, just changing some of it's behavior based on the arguments you have.

Now all you need to do is to swap out fragments in your container, while still staying in one Activity only. Since your question was kinda vague, I cannot offer any implementation tips at this point, but rather a basic guideline and a direction to consider.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear and fast answer, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: You are very welcome! You should learn a bit more about the fragments in order to do this, but this is not at all very hard. Enjoy coding bro!

Answer (score 2):

If changing to a new background is all a change of levels will trigger, I would just add a level member variable to the activity and (for instance) listen for the next level in order to change the background. If it turns out that you will have to change more than the background, @Vucko s answer seems viable.

Definitely do not repeat the same code fifty times in fifty different activities!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a BaseActivity that will be extended from all other activities for code centralization. Otherwise you can use always the same activity and start it with a parameter in the intent (for example, level number) and make your own logics according parameter value. Finally, you can give a look to fragments too, keeping central logic in the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment is your solution, you can simply pass the background assets name (throw intent).